# Can I slow an air cooler's fan speed with an additional regulator?

Tags: electrical-panel, regulator

I recently got an [air cooler](https://www.symphonylimited.com/symphony-touch-110-room-air-cooler-110-litres.html) which has a fan speed regulator. Still, the lowest setting gives high airflow.

Can I wire it to a fan regulator to limit the air flow without damaging the cooler's electricals?

I understand that the cooler water pump will also receive less electricity.

Edit: It's a [swamp cooler](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1Z1zW-nGNiw13aAB5UR3sTL7eUaEaQZk-6Tm5ATRNUfckAdG0OMBggNg&s=10)
I believe the fan speed regulator controls voltage output. So I am planning to add additional voltage regulator in board.
[Like this, instead of fan in image , it will be cooler](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVensTPIxVfLhehfUcBafMwzkJPgfE-UCttA&usqp=CAU)

Comment: Appliance modification isn't really within our scope here. You might try an electronics forum.

Comment: @isherwood - not sure it is a normal question but seems within scope.

Comment: Small appliance repair is off-topic. You could call this a major appliance, but outright modification is beyond that, I'd say. It gets into warranty and liability issues.

Comment: Tell us what type cooler it is. Is it an evaporator cooler often called a swamp cooler, is it an A/C unit, Explain what it is before anyone can try to give any guidance. A picture and some model numbers would help.

Comment: Product link updated.

Comment: Is the problem the actual airflow or the noise? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: d.George: updated the question. It's swamp cooler.

Comment: @isherwood:  problem is airflow. I like to have slower air flow when I am alone working in room. But need higher flow, when more people are there.

Comment: Put something in front of the air outlet to deflect or diffuse the air flow when you don't want it to blow so hard. Move the thing when you want full power air flow.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. _What's the problem with the airflow_? Is it uncomfortable? Does it blow your papers around? Is it loud?

Comment: @isherwood : The heavy flow is uncomfortable and bit loud. I would prefer slow cooling with breeze air.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the photo and the units size I am guessing it is a evaporative cooler commonly called a swamp cooler as the water falling down with air flow creates cool air. If this is the case you could slow the fan but remember the cooling is based on the air flow.

If I am wrong and the cooler uses a refrigerant you should not adjust the fan as slowing the fan can cause the system to ice up. Icing affects system performance and in severe cases can damage the evaporator coils.

Comment: Ed, "*If this is the case you could slow the fan*"  How would they do that without damaging the cooler's electricals?

Comment: It's swamp cooler. So I can plug it point with voltage regulator and good to go..

Comment: Using a regulator on the fan motor would work. Taking the output from the controls and adjusting the pulse with or voltage would adjust the motor speed without damaging the controls themselves.